# Google Map doesn't load in Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a sliding tab fragment with two windows and the first one contains a google map view. The Fragments work fine and the Google fragment also gets shown, but the map doesn't load. Only a blank map with grid lines and a google logo gets shown. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class CardFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
private int position;

GoogleMap mMap;
Geocoder coder;

public static CardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    CardFragment f = new CardFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

public static MapsFragment newInstance(String s) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("value", s);
    MapsFragment result = new MapsFragment();
    result.setArguments(args);
    return result;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);      
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(position == 0){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_frag,container,false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
        ViewCompat.setElevation(rootView, 50);

        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.getContext()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            MapView mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mymap);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        return rootView;
    } else {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag,container,false);
        ViewCompat.setElevation(rootView, 50);
        return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    coder = new Geocoder(this.getContext());
    p1 = null;
}
```

layout maps_frag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swagishmap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.locustapps.ingredientsapp.MapsActivity"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: White you have to use SupportMapFragment answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with MapView giving a name of `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`.  That doesn't make any sense.

If you want to put a Map in a Fragment, you should use a [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) or a [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) if using the compatibility library for fragments.  These fragments will manage the display of a map in the fragment's space.

The [ApiDemos](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos) sample project has examples of how to use it.  [Here is a layout](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/c3bad6156de29fd8fe9333add5303ba4739233a0/ApiDemos/app/src/main/res/layout/multimap_demo.xml) that declares a SupportMapView fragment.